# Azure vault key using .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have an Azure account and I need to do this using.NEt 4.5 class library

- Create Key Vault Resource
- Add Secrets to the Key Vault
- Provision Web App Infrastructure
- Create a Managed Service Identity
- Build an ASP.NET Core Web App
- Deploy and Validate the Web App

I have found few articles but no complete articles or mostly using asp.net Core. I need to create it using .Net 4.5

Can you please suggest solution?

Comment: You should handle all this IaC with Terraform/powershell/Azue Cli. Not with .NET

Comment: @JuanmaFeliu This is the requirement from client to do this using C#

Comment: Ok, nosense sorry :-) Talk them how to run pipelines in DevOps.

Answer (score 2):

We can use Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent library to manage Azure resources
(https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent/)

Combined with ARM template for each of the resources  (KeyVault, WebApp and any other resource) we can create the resource by calling the Fluent library for each template

Providing sample code below for creating Storage Account using Fluent library

```
string tenantId = "";
string clientId = "";
string clientSecret = "";
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(clientId, clientSecret, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
var azure = Azure.Configure().WithLogLevel(Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic).Authenticate(credentials).WithSubscription("<<subscriptionid>>");

var templateString = File.ReadAllText("storageaccountARMTemplate.json");
var resourceName = "storageaccounttemplate";
var resourceGroupName = "rglearnazure";
            azure.Deployments.Define(resourceName).WithExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroupName).WithTemplate(templateString).WithParameters("{}").WithMode(DeploymentMode.Incremental).Create();
```

Comment: I've got some questions for you. I recognize some of this from working with Azure, but I've never written C# code that uses it. What namespace does SdkContext come from? And how about Azure, as in `Azure.Configure()`... what namespace is Azure from?